# How to tell which key was not found?

Tags: c#, .net, exception

I have a `Configuration` class that has a number of settings in it. A simple example:

```
class Configuration
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    //There are about 20 of these
}
```

I would like to offer the caller the ability to populate this object from a string dictionary, like so:

```
static Configuration CreateFromDictionary(Dictionary<string, string> dict)
{
    try
    {
        return new Configuration
        {
            Name     = dict["Name"],
            Url      = dict["Url"],
            Password = dict["Password"]
        }
    }
    catch(KeyNotFoundException exception)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("Unable to construct a Configuration from the information given.");
    }
}
```

This works well, except it's an all-or-nothing conversion. If the caller provides a dictionary that is mostly good but one of the entries is misspelled, the conversion fails with an exception.

I'd like to be able to provide a better exception message that tells the caller *which* key was not found. Seems sort of important. But I am unable to retrieve that information from the `KeyNotFoundException`.

I could write code to parse the dictionary one line at a time and check for each key individually, but that seems like a real pain. Is there any way to tell which key was not found from the exception information or without searching for keys one line at a time with `ContainsKey` or `TryGetValue`?

Comment: collect the values at the start.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the exception 'KeyNotFoundException' thrown from indexer in `Dictionary<,>` doesn't provide the 'key' value in error message.

Below is the generic extension method you can use to get detailed exception. Also in your code in the catch block you are swallowing the exception. Instead put it in as InnerException so it gets logged properly.

```
static Configuration CreateFromDictionary(Dictionary<string, string> dict)
{
            try
    {
        return new Configuration
        {
            Name = dict.GetValue("Name"),
            Url = dict.GetValue("Url"),
            Password = dict.GetValue("Password")
        }
    }
    catch (KeyNotFoundException ex)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("Unable to construct a Configuration from the information given.", ex);
    }
 }

public static class ExtensionsUtil
{
    public static Tvalue GetValue<Tvalue, TKey>(this Dictionary<TKey, Tvalue> dict, TKey key)
    {
        Tvalue val = default(Tvalue);
        if (dict.TryGetValue(key, out val))
        {
            return val;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new KeyNotFoundException($"'{key}' not found in the collection.");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can store the keys along with their mappings in a dictionary, and validate the input before mapping the values:

```
public static Configuration CreateFromDictionary(Dictionary<string, string> dict)
{
    var mappings = new Dictionary<string, Action<Configuration, string>>
    {
        [nameof(Name)] = (x, value) => x.Name = value,
        [nameof(Url)] = (x, value) => x.Url = value,
        [nameof(Password)] = (x, value) => x.Password = value,
    };

    var missingKeys = mappings.Keys
        .Except(dict.Keys)
        .ToArray();
    if (missingKeys.Any())
        throw new KeyNotFoundException("The given keys are missing: " + string.Join(", ", missingKeys));

    return mappings.Aggregate(new Configuration(), (config, mapping) =>
    {
        mapping.Value(config, dict[mapping.Key]);
        return config;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the "TryGetValue" method of the dictionary, and ditch the catch handler.  The result of TryGetValue will be false if the key is not found, or true if it is.  There is an "out" paremeter where the value will be, if true is returned.  In lieu of your catch handler, you only have to keep track of which keys are not present (again indicated by the return value of false from TryGetValue).

Quick example:

```
string name;
Configuration config = new Configuration();
if (dict.TryGetValue("Name", out name))
{
    config.Name = name;
}
else
{
    throw new ArgumentException("'Name' was not present.");
}
```

EDIT:
In light of the clarification made to the question, I'm going to revise my answer to: No, it is not possible to get that information from the exception.

Comment: I think you're missing the spirit of the question. Of course I could check for keys one by one, and I know how to do that. The question is whether it is necessary.

Comment: @JohnWu I guess you're right, I must have missed the spirit of the question, and I think I still am.

Answer (score 0):

The way I have solved this problem in the past is to wrap the real dictionary:

```
public class MyDictionary<TKey, TValue> : IDictionary<TKey, TValue>
{
    public MyDictionary(IDictionary<TKey, TValue> realDictionary)
    {
         _dictionary = realDictionary;
    }

    ...

    public TValue this[TKey key]
    {
        get
        {
            try
            {
                return _dictionary[key];
            }
            catch (KeyNotFoundException e)
            {
                throw new KeyNotFoundException($"Key {key} is not in the dictionary", e);
            }
        }
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Unfortunately the built-in exception simply doesn't provide the information.

Answer (score 0):

My solution so far is to use an extension method:

```
public static T ParseFor<T>(this IDictionary<string, string> source, string key)
{
    string val;
    if (!source.TryGetValue(key, out val)) throw new KeyNotFoundException(string.Format("An entry for '{0}' was not found in the dictionary", key));
    try
    {
        return (T)Convert.ChangeType(val, typeof(T));
    }
    catch
    {
        throw new FormatException(string.Format("The value for '{0}' ('{1}') was not in a correct format to be converted to a {2}", key, val, typeof(T).Name));
    }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
return new Configuration
    {
        Name     = dict.ParseFor<string>("Name"),
        Url      = dict.ParseFor<string>("Url"),
        Password = dict.PasreFor<string>("Password")
    }
```

The extension method will throw a helpful exception containing the key name. Also has the benefit of supporting type conversion, e.g. if one of the configuration items is a `bool` it'll attempt to convert it.

Comment: What if two keys are misspelled?

Comment: You generic method will only work on `Dictionary<string,string>`. Also you are swallowing the exception thrown from Extension method. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a builder which will find properties of type 'string' that exist in your `Configuration` type, and then loop through these properties trying to fetch each one from given dictionary. This code even can be generic:

```
public T Build<T>(Dictionary<string, string> source)
    where T : new()
{
    var flags = BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.SetProperty;
    var properties = typeof(T).GetProperties(flags)
         .Where(p => p.PropertyType == typeof(string));

    var missingKeys = properties.Select(p => p.Name).Except(source.Keys);
    if (missingKeys.Any())
        throw new FooException($"These keys not found: {String.Join(", ", missingKeys)}");

    var obj = new T();

    foreach (var p in properties)
        p.SetValue(obj, source[p.Name]);

    return obj;
}
```

Usage:

```
// throws FooException if any key  is missing
var config = Something.Build<Configuration>(dict);
```

But usually, configurations do not contain strings.

- What if `Url` is not valid uri?
- What if `Name` is empty?
- What if `Password` is `null` in dictionary?
- What if some numeric setting is not a parsable string? Etc.

In all these cases your code will be happy and you'll get an exception at runtime. Things become much better if you use specific types for your settings `string`, `Uri`, `int`, `DateTime` etc. And validated these values as soon as you can. Also usually some settings are optional - you should not throw if this setting is missing in dictionary or whatever source you are using.

```
public class Configuration
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Uri Url { get; set; }
    public int RequiredNumber { get; set; }
    public int? NotRequiredNumber { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can create set of extension methods which try to get and parse values from dictionary:

```
public static Uri GetUri(this Dictionary<string, string> source, string key)
{
    if (!source.TryGetValue(key, out string value))
        throw new ConfigurationException($"{key} not found");

    if (!Uri.TryCreate(value, UriKind.Absolute, out Uri result))
        throw new ConfigurationException($"{key} is not a valid uri: {value}");

    return result;
}
```

And creating configuration will look like

```
var config = new Configuration {
    Name = dict.GetString("Name"),
    Url = dict.GetUri("Uri"),
    RequiredNumber = dict.GetInt("RequiredNumber"),
    NotRequiredNumber = dict.GetNullableInt("NotRequiredNumber")
};
```

Your code will fail fast if something is misconfigured. And you will be pretty safe if config is created.

Answer (score 0):

Here what you can do.

```
  static Configuration CreateConfiguration(Dictionary<string,string> dict)
    {
        try
        {
            return
                new Configuration
                {
                    FirstName = dict.getValue("FirstName"),
                    LastName = dict.getValue("LastName"),
                    ID = dict.getValue("ID")                        
                };
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }

    public static class Extension
{
    public static string getValue(this Dictionary<string, String> dict, string keyName)
    {
        string data = null;
        var result = dict.TryGetValue(keyName, out data);
        if (!result)
            throw new KeyNotFoundException($"The given key '{keyName}' was not present in the dictionary. keyname is not found");
        return data;
    }
}
```